# SQL Join - explanation needed

Tags: mysql

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT A.*, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(I.Image, '@', I.Local, '@', I.Primary) SEPARATOR ',') AS _Images, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT H.LocationId SEPARATOR ',') AS _Hierarchy, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Am.AmenityId SEPARATOR ',') AS _Amenities 
FROM Ads as A 
    LEFT JOIN ImagesTable as I ON I.AdId = A.AdId 
    LEFT JOIN HierarchyTable as H ON H.AdId = A.AdId 
    LEFT JOIN AmenitiesTable as Am ON Am.AdId = A.AdId 
WHERE A.AdId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) 
GROUP BY A.AdId
```

Let's say that the table `Ads` has ~1.000.000 rows. When this query is ran with MySQL, how would MySQL process this query?

Will it process the JOIN operations on the ~1.000.000 rows of the table `Ads`, or will it only process it on the specific ids provided in the where clause at the end of the query?

With 200 rows specified in the where clause, a query like this takes around ~0.9 seconds for me, and I am trying to quicken it up a bit. That's why I am interested if I could fasten this query in any way, for example by telling MySQL to only process the desired rows, and not the whole table `Ads`.

Comment: In MySQL you may use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see , how MySQL is working on the statement

Comment: *"telling MySQL to only process the desired rows, and not the whole table Ads."* -- the table `Ads` appears on the left side of a `LEFT JOIN` and that means at the join level all the rows from `Ads` appear in the result set. But MySQL also processes as much as it can from the `WHERE` clause together with the join clauses in order to avoid working for rows that won't make it to the final result set. An index on the `AdId` column of table `Ads` helps both the filtering (the `WHERE` clause) and the joins (`A.AdId` appears on the `ON` conditions). The same for `H.AdID` and `Am.AdId`.

Comment: All of these indexings are already present unfortunately.:(

Comment: Yes, `WHERE A.AdId IN ...` and the joins will only access the rows required (so especially for your `ads` table, it will access only the rows with `A.AdId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`) - IF you have the correct indexex on your tables. Without adding your `explain` output and the index definitions for at least the indexes used, it is up to you to decide if they are correct. Do you have more than 1 row per `AId` in `Ads`? 10 rows should not take 1 second (if your other tables are reasonable small). On a side note: `select A.*` with `GROUP BY A.AdId` might not give you the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

When field A.AdId is indexed then database engine will search all A.AdId only in indexes store to get position rows in full table. => fast

When field A.AdId is not indexed then database engine will parse all rown in full table to search all A.AdId. => very slow

When database engine get A.AdId it will use them to join on another table.